# How can i fetch data from realtime database using firebase v9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering how can I fetch the data everytime I create a new guest through form using **realtime database** in **firebase v9**? I was trying to find the ways of doing it on the internet but I couldn't. So i want to fetch data from realtime database everytime i submit my form and show the data in a table. Also is there and easier way to send data than I did it here using set and ref? Thanks.

*Here is the existing code:*

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form class="form">
    <span>Guest name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <span>Guest surname:</span>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br>
    <span>Tel:</span>
    <input type="number" name="tel" id="tel" maxlength="16"><br>
    <span>Country:</span>
    <input type="text" name="country" id="country"><br>
    <span>Arrival date:</span>
    <input type="date" name="arrivalDate" id="arrivalDate"><br>
    <span>Departure date:</span>
    <input type="date" name="departureDate" id="departureDate"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  <p class="success"></p>
</body
```

jQuery:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";

  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "hidden",
    authDomain: "hidden",
    databaseURL: "hidden",
    projectId: "reservations-32294",
    storageBucket: "reservations-32294.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "773498700596",
    appId: "1:773498700596:web:618889de8423f066071b61"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";

  const db = getDatabase();

  function insertData() {
    set(ref(db, "Guests/" + $("#name").val() + " " + $("#surname").val()), {
      Name: $("#name").val(),
      Surnam: $("#surname").val(),
      Tel: $("#tel").val(),
      Country: $("#country").val(),
      ArrivalDate: formatDate($("#arrivalDate").val()),
      DepartureDate: formatDate($("#departureDate").val())
    })
    .then(() => {
      $(".success").html("Success!").fadeIn("fast");;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.success').fadeOut('fast');
      }, 2000);
      $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error));
  }

  $(".form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input").attr("disabled", "true");
    insertData();
  });

  const formatDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = date.split("-");
    let day = newDate[2];
    let month = newDate[1];
    let year = newDate[0];
    let newFormat = `${day}.${month}.${year}.`;
    return newFormat;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read data with the `get` method and listen for changes with `onValue` method.

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set, get, onValue } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";
        
const db = getDatabase();
const guestsRef = ref(db, 'Guests');

onValue(guestsRef , (snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    // Do something with your data.
  }
});
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to delete data on button click?

Comment: @russelhd you will need to import delete method then create a button with an attribute that has "name surname" value then you can call remove(ref(db, 'Guests/${name surname}')) << expect with back ticks (cant add back ticks here!)